# how can i make table to store all actions (create - update - delete) in every tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i need to create table to store any action in other tables in my  database
any help to

this table will store name of the table and field that has the action

the result can be date (updated - create - deleted ) and table name and field name

Comment: *"how can i make table to store all actions (create - update - delete) in every tables"* that would require one table to store the information and source and action.. And on every table you want to "enable" this you would have to create three triggers for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: so i should make 1-(table names of tables) 2-(tables - actions types create-update-delete) 3-(table have table name and action and date )

Comment: No idea what you mean..

Comment: i will create 4 tables 1-table-of-tables(id,table_name)     2-table-of-fields(id,filed_name and table_id#)      3-table-of--action-type(id-type->"create-update-delete")    4-table-of-actions(id,field_id# , action_type_id# , date)

Comment: As @RaymondNijland said you create triggers, but that's going to slow you down a lot if you are going to record a row for every updated column. Consider at least creating an audit database that has an audit table for every source table, and records the whole row for each update/delete/insert